# Using Geopackages and Drive in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geopackage

I have been working with geopackages at a company where we have all our data sync in a drive. The thing is that when I save a project, QGIS creates an extra geopackage with the same name as the original + compute name.

Why does this happens?

How can I be sure that all the changes are in the original geopackage?

Comment: Do both geopackage files end with the suffix ".gpkg"?  Are they the same size?  What version of QGIS?  What operating system?

Comment: yes, both ends with .gpkg same size, windows 10. Even a change in the symbology creates a new geopackage named as: OriginalGeopackageName_UserComputer_1 (or 2, 3 if the person does more changes) My guess is that maybe the problem is due to issues when syncing with drive but I'm not sure.

Comment: I have been struggling with limitations of google drive (file stream in my case) and how geopackages work in QGIS. Whenever a qgis file is opened that contains a .gpkg google decides that the file has changed and uploads it even if no changes have been made. I think that if that happens on 2 separate machines google will create a duplicate file appended with the computer name. I haven't figured it out but in theory you can load it in a different mode and have this not happen. https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/36741